# How do Shell Psions and A.C.I.D combine?

Tags: into-the-breach

When an enemy is coated in A.C.I.D., they take double damage. When a Shell Psion is on the field, all enemies take one less damage.

So say both effects are in play, and I hit the enemy with an attack that deals `n` damage. Does it take `2n` damage due to the A.C.I.D., but reduced by one because of the Psion, for a total of `2n-1`? Or does the attack only deal `n-1` damage because of the Psion, which is then doubled because of the A.C.I.D. for a total of `2n-2`?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, A.C.I.D. just entirely cancels the effect of the Shell Psion, so you'll deal `2n` damage. It looks like this:

[image]

You can see the Shell Psion buff icon is crossed out.

Comment: Certain enemies, mechs, and Abe can have armor naturally. A.C.I.D. also removes it.